# Path with '/' in json-server db.json

Tags: javascript, json-server

i use [server-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) to have a fake API, i have the path  "playbook/active" in data.json

```js
"playbook/active": [{
    "description": "This playbook will install haproxy",
    "name": "Testing playbook 3",
    "tag": [
      "loadbalancer",
      "charge"
    ],
    "path": "/etc/ansible/haproxy.yml",
    "type": "action",
    "id": "4bb107be-9efe-11e9-b3e5-bc5ff4901aa5"
  },
  {
    "path": "google.com",
    "description": "This is the playbook before execution",
    "tag": [
      "webserver",
      "tomcat"
    ],
    "id": "faa746b4-9cb7-11e9-9b94-bc5ff4901aa5",
    "name": "mysql"
  }
]
```

but i have this error

> Error: Oops, found / character in database property 'playbook/active'.

I change to "playbook/active"  but same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Providing a complete answer (showcase example)

Configuring `db.json` and `routes.json` can do the trick for you:

- db.json

```json
{
    "playbookActive": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Active Playbook 1",
            "description": "Description 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Active Playbook 2",
            "description": "Description 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

routes.json

```json
{
    "/playbook/active": "/playbookActive",
    "/playbook/active/:id": "/playbookActive/:id"
}
```

> Note: the mapping in routes.json is goes like this: `[expanded/endpoint]: aliasEndpoint` where *aliasEndpoint* should match the one from db.json.

package.json

```json
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "api": "json-server [path-to-db.json] --routes [path-to-routes.json] --no-cors=false"
    },
    ...
}
```

Verify the routing on start (logs from `npm run api`):

```
Resources
http://localhost:3000/playbookActive

Other routes
/playbook/active -> /playbookActive
/playbook/active/:id -> /playbookActive/:id

Home
http://localhost:3000
```

### Examples

##### GET → http://localhost:3000/playbook/active

*Response contains a list with all the active playbooks*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Active Playbook 1",
    "description": "Description 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Active Playbook 2",
    "description": "Description 2"
  }
]
```

##### GET → http://localhost:3000/playbook/active/2

*Response contains the active playbook that matches id=2*:

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Active Playbook 2",
  "description": "Description 2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the error message:

> Oops, found / character in database property 'dossier/la'.
>
> / aren't supported, if you want to tweak default routes, see
>   https://github.com/typicode/json-server/#add-custom-routes

It seems that slashes are not supported.

The solution is to create a `routes.json` file containing the mapping for your url.

For example the contents of this file could be:

```
{
  my-awesome-endpoint": "playbook/active"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

> db.json

```
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "abcde",
            "tel": "123454323",
            "id": 5
        }
    ]
```

> routes.json

```
{
    "/v1/list?type=hot": "/list"
}
```

start command:

```
npx json-server --watch db.json --routes routes.json
```